# grouped <g> dynamic svg in vue 3 not displaying

Tags: svg, vuejs3

I am trying to display an svg image url that will be dynamically generated, and displayed in a svg group  with other svgs.

However the png does not display when i use :href

The first four images tags do not work but the last 3 ones do.

I would prefer to use packed assets rather than public images, but cannot seem to get them working.

Here is the sandbox
[SandBox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/lucid-hellman-qv2ym8)

And here is the main component

```
`<template>
  <div>
    <svg>
      <g>
        <!-- These Don't Work -->
        <image width="200" href="../assets/Bananas.svg"></image>
        <image width="200" :href="Bananas"></image>
        <image width="200" :href="Bananas1"></image>
        <image width="200" :href="myimage"></image>

        <!-- These Work -->
        <!-- <image width="200 " href="https://qv2ym8.csb.app/Bananas.svg"></image> -->
        <!-- <image width="200" :href="myimage1"></image> -->
        <!-- <image width="200" :href="myimage2"></image> -->
      </g>
    </svg>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import {
  ref,
  reactive,
  nextTick,
  computed,
  watch,
  onMounted,
  onBeforeUnmount,
} from "vue";
import Bananas from "/src/assets/Bananas.svg";
import Bananas1 from "/public/Bananas.svg";

const myimage = computed(() => {
  return "/src/assets/Bananas.svg";
});

const myimage1 = computed(() => {
  return "https://qv2ym8.csb.app/Bananas.svg";
});

const myimage2 = computed(() => {
  return "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f7/Bananas.svg";
});
</script>`
```

From the code you can see I tried importing and using computed properties, but cannot get it working with packed assets.

Comment: Are you using Nuxt?

Comment: Also on your image path the code reference with `href` instead of `src`.

Comment: @John Philip - yes i was using nuxt3 but got a similar issue with just vue like in the sandbox. <image> uses href it does not have a src https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/image